# How to access inserted data from table?

Tags: list-manipulation, insert

I'm inserting a number into the first column of a table, but when I call the table again, the number is not there anymore. Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
In[22]:= mass[n]

Out[22]= {5.07637*10^24, 8.24164*10^24, 2.4486*10^24, 3.70276*10^24, 
4.0611*10^24, 8.00275*10^24, 2.74721*10^24}

In[23]:= Insert[mass[n], 1.59084*10^29, 1]

Out[23]= {1.59084*10^29, 5.07637*10^24, 8.24164*10^24, 2.4486*10^24, 
3.70276*10^24, 4.0611*10^24, 8.00275*10^24, 2.74721*10^24}

In[24]:= mass[n][[1]]

Out[24]= 5.07637*10^24

In[25]:= mass[n]

Out[25]= {5.07637*10^24, 8.24164*10^24, 2.4486*10^24, 3.70276*10^24, 
4.0611*10^24, 8.00275*10^24, 2.74721*10^24}
```

Comment: `Insert` is not an in-place modification (these end usually with a `To` like `AddTo`). In your case, you may use `mass[n] = Insert[mass[n], 1.59084*10^29, 1]` or `PrependTo[mass[n],1.59084*10^29]` which are both not really optimal since they involve a copy of the whole list. So use that rarely for longer lists. If you can, try to build vectors, matrices, and more general arrays in one go (e.g. with `Table`) or at least boil it down to few `Join` or `ArrayFlatten` operations.